# How to inherit a template with no ID in Odoo?

Tags: templates, odoo

I am trying to show the date a change was made in a task. To do this, I need to inherit the template of the widget "mail_thread". That template hasn't an id in its definition. This is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>

    <!--
        mail.Widget template used to namespace the css -->
    <t t-name="mail.Root">
        <div class="oe_mail">
        </div>
    </t>

...


                    <span t-att-title="widget.date">
                        <t t-if="widget.timerelative" t-esc="widget.timerelative"/>
                        <t t-if="!widget.timerelative" t-raw="widget.display_date"/>
                    </span>



...

</template>
```

In my module, I need to replace the `<span>` tag in order to show the date.

So, how to inherit that template and replace the  tag?

Answer (score 11):

There are different inheritance mechanism for client side templates (web templates, defined inside a `<templates>` tag, "compiled" with javascript in the client when loading it) and server-side templates (usually views, must be included in the data list in the `__openerp__.py` file, 'compiled' when launching/upgrading the odoo server).

You extend web/widget templates templates using `<t t-extend="template_name">` followed by one or more
`<t t-jquery="jquery_selector" t-operation="operation">` which acts kinda like xpath, but client side and more 'powerful'.
You don't need ids, inheritance is based on the template name. (`t-name` directive)

- [Server-Side view inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#inheritance)
- [Client-Side template inheritance:](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html#javascript)

> Template inheritance is used to alter existing templates in-place,
>   e.g. to add information to templates created by an other modules.
>
> Template inheritance is performed via the t-extend directive which
>   takes the name of the template to alter as parameter.
>
> The alteration is then performed with any number of t-jquery
>   sub-directives:
>
> `<t t-extend="base.template">
>       <t t-jquery="ul" t-operation="append">
>           <li>new element</li>
>       </t> </t>`
>
> The t-jquery directives takes a CSS selector. This selector is used on
>   the extended template to select context nodes to which the specified
>   t-operation is applied:
>
> - append
>     the node’s body is appended at the end of the context node (after the context node’s last child)
> - prepend
>     the node’s body is prepended to the context node (inserted before the context node’s first child)
> - before
>     the node’s body is inserted right before the context node
> - after
>     the node’s body is inserted right after the context node
> - inner
>     the node’s body replaces the context node’s children
> - replace
>     the node’s body is used to replace the context node itsel
> - No operation
>     if no t-operation is specified, the template body is interpreted as javascript code and executed with the context node as this

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to change the date show format in this xml file. So I copied the whole template for this default layout to my new module and only changed date in the span tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>

    <!-- default layout -->
    <t t-name="mail.thread.message">
    ....

        <span t-att-title="widget.date">
            <!--<t t-if="widget.timerelative" t-esc="widget.timerelative"/>-->
            <!--<t t-if="!widget.timerelative" t-raw="widget.display_date"/>-->
            <t t-raw="widget.display_date"/>
        </span>

    ....
    </t>
</template>
```

need to declare this xml file in your **__openerp__.py**

It worked for me.