# Odoo 9 qweb inheritance

Tags: dom, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

In opportunity kanban view I want to remove certain element. It is a span in web_kanban template with t-name="Kanban.Group". I followed this thread [How to inherit a template with no ID in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907963/how-to-inherit-a-template-with-no-id-in-odoo) and related documentation.

I put this

```
<t t-extend="KanbanView.Group">
    <t t-jquery="span.o_kanban_config" t-operation="replace"></t>
</t>
```

in opportunities kanban template and I also made it a separate xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template>
        <t t-extend="KanbanView.Group">
            <t t-jquery="span.o_kanban_config" t-operation="replace"></t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

(in this case I appended its name to module's manifest - in 'qweb' list). None of these approaches worked.

Contrary to what I have read about template inheritance, I also tried to use `<t t-extend="web_kanban.template">`, just in case Odoo needs the modules name just like when inheriting classic views...

Did I do something wrong or miss something? Is there a better/more suitable way to update template?

---

SOLVED

Finally it works.

I created a separate xml. As I decided to have folding arrows I put this code in it:

```
<template>
    <t t-extend="KanbanView.Group">
        <t t-jquery=".o_kanban_config.dropdown" t-operation="inner">
                <a class="o_kanban_toggle_fold" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"/></a>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

I added a declaration to **openerp**.py manifest:

```
'qweb':[
    'views/updated_kanban.xml',
],
```

Now only a folding arrow is displayed, no other options (Edit, duplicate etc.).

Comment: It works finally. Don't know what happened, probably a browser restart or something. I inherited a template as written in question, but without xml declaration and <odoo> element. XML is declared in 'qweb' list of manifest.

Answer (score 0):

OInherting Kanban is `regular` view and has to be inherited like regular views inheritance and [this link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/crm/res_partner_view.xml#L60) is the example of the Kanban view inheritance. Kanban view contain qweb but its not actual qWeb template so follow [view inheritance document here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/views.html#inheritance)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The links you have provided really show how to edit a template within a regular view. However, I want to edit a real template defined in different module `addons/web_kanban/static/xml/web_kanban.xml`. It is an xml with following structure: `<template><t t-name='...'>...</t><t>...</t></template>`. I cannot use the above mentioned approach as I cannot refer to the entities defined outside the view (I tried anyway, just to see what happens)